# ubuntu 16.04 boot from launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a robot to install Ubuntu 16.04 now, want to boot a launch file, but tried a lot of methods effect is not ideal, used to start in the /etc/rc.local file, Su firefly -c "/etc/init.d/start_ros.sh" after the start, without any operation of the nodes, and the use of robot_upstart, URI and hostname cannot be specified for master, if you can provide effective the method, thank you very much

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275156/ubuntu-16.04-boot-from-launch-file/) by [owen.yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32518/owen.yang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-11-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Another option is to use `systemd`. A simple example:

Contents of `/lib/systemd/system/robot.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=My Robot

[Service]
User=root
ExecStart=/home/me/catkin_ws/src/robot/scripts/start_robot.sh

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Contents of `/home/myaccount/catkin_ws/src/robot/scripts/start_robot.sh`:

```
bash -c "source /home/me/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash && roslaunch robot robot.launch"
```

Then use `systemctl` to control it:

```
sudo systemctl start robot.service # start
sudo systemctl stop robot.service # stop
sudo systemctl enable robot.service # start on boot
sudo systemctl disable robot.service # disable start on boot
```

(Edit to add some debugging notes.)

Note that you can set "User=." Debugging will be easier if you can use your typical login. Of course, you should never use root unless you absolutely have to.

Debugging a boot-time launch can be annoying, since you need to rely on logging. I typically use `roslaunch --screen` from the command line to develop and debug, then move to manual start/stop to do system tests, then only when when I'm ready to do a full end-to-end test do I enable start at boot.

A few tricks for debugging:

Set `output="log"` on all nodes. (The default is output to log, so you can just remove the `output="screen"` option as well.) This will send all ROS_INFO messages to log files so that they don't clutter up the `systemd` logs.

Add `stdbuf -oL` to your command line invocations:

```
bash -c "source /home/myaccount/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash && stdbuf -oL roslaunch robot robot.launch"
```

This will flush the output buffers after every line so that you see log messages quickly.

To see errors, run `systemctl status robot.service`. To see ROS_INFO messages, run `tail -f ~/.ros/log/latest/mynode-*-stdout.log"`.

---

Originally posted by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) with karma: 1247 on 2017-11-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [owen.yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32518/owen.yang/) on 2017-11-12**:
Thank you for your advice, I follow the tutorial to try, but still failed, my ros system, installed under the non-root user, do not know what effect this.

**Comment by [clyde](https://answers.ros.org/users/28405/clyde/) on 2017-11-13**:
I added a few notes on debugging. If you provide more info it'll be easier to diagnose the problem.

**Comment by [owen.yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32518/owen.yang/) on 2017-11-13**:
sudo systemctl status robot.service,this is output.
enter code here**● robot.service - My Robot
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/robot.service; enabled; vendor preset: en
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since 二 2017-11-14 09:30:10 CST; 54s ago
Main PID: 828 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)**

**Comment by [owen.yang](https://answers.ros.org/users/32518/owen.yang/) on 2017-11-13**:
I see `~/.ros/log/latest/mynode-*-stdout.log`,there is not log file.So I can not provide more information, if I can, I can send you an email describing my complete operation